# `git log -p`: showing diff or generating patch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-log

When reading the documentation of git, I seemed to find a contradiction.

In [this official tutorial of git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial#_viewing_project_history), `git log -p` is said to show the history of commits together with complete diff info. However, in [the documentation of git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_generating_patches_with_p), the `-p` option is said to produce a patch file instead of directly output. Also, the description "they do not produce the output described above" is confusing, since the "described above" is very vague, at least for me.

Other than the section given above, I only find [one other place](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---full-diff) mentioning the `-p` option, which matches the description in the tutorial instead of the patch part. Also, when I run `git log -p` on my computer, its shows commit history together with diff info, and I  don't see any patch files generated. So are the two parts of the documentation contradictory? Or do I misunderstood the process of "generating patch files"? Thank you!

Comment: They produce it on standard output, which is a file.    It's often attached to a terminal, but it doesn't have to be.  It doesn't matter what kind of file it's attached to, it's still a file.  Pipes, terminals, other network connections, storage, ... all files.

Comment: I've just submitted a patch to the Git mailing list that changes the documentation: it should say "patch text" instead of "patches" or "patch files". I hope this wording does not let you expect that files are created and avoids the confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a lot of Git documentation that is ... suboptimal, shall we say.

It's important to realize that each Git commit saves a snapshot, rather than changes, as this explains the behavior of Git in several trickier cases.  Various Git commands—including both `git diff` and `git log`—can then extract *two* snapshots and compare them.  The result of comparing an older snapshot to a newer snapshot—or a "left side" to a "right side", because you can reverse it and compare the newer to the older instead—is a *diff* or *patch*.

The default method of preparing such a diff / patch is to produce a series of instructions that, if obeyed to the letter, will transform each left-side file into the corresponding right-side file.  These instructions have the general form of: *Expect this particular context to be viewable in both the left and right side files, and then delete any `-` lines from the left-side file and add any `+` lines from the right-side file.*  If the left-side file is from the (singular) *parent* of some commit, and the right-side file is from the commit itself, that tells you what someone changed in that file.

No doubt you have seen this output, and it probably even makes some sense.

The documentation you're reading, however, is compiled automatically from multiple input fragments, and the [`git log` description to which you linked](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_generating_patches_with_p) was written to be read after [this other description of the *default* output of `git diff-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#_raw_output_format), which includes this particular text:

> ```
> in-place edit  :100644 100644 bcd1234 0123456 M file0
> copy-edit      :100644 100644 abcd123 1234567 C68 file1 file2
> rename-edit    :100644 100644 abcd123 1234567 R86 file1 file3
> create         :000000 100644 0000000 1234567 A file4
> delete         :100644 000000 1234567 0000000 D file5
> unmerged       :000000 000000 0000000 0000000 U file6
> ```

Of course, `git log -p` does not produce that output at all—so the `git log` documentation doesn't *include* this section.  But `git log -p` *does* produce the same output as `git diff-tree -p`.  When the *later* section of `git diff-tree -p` documentation uses the phrase "do[es] not produce the output described above", it's talking about the `:100644 ...` stuff.

#### [Tell me lies, tell me sweet little lies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lies)

Going back to the claim that `git log -p`

> show[s] the history of commits together with complete diff info

—well, this too is false.  The problem here is that *complete* information is too complex for `git log -p`.  Specifically, *merge* commits are defined as any commit that has *two or more parent commits*.

Every commit saves a snapshot of all of your files.  But every commit *also* records some set of *parent*, or predecessor, commit hash IDs.  Most commits have exactly one parent.  In this particular—and very common—case, `git log` can run `git diff` with the (singular) parent on the left side, and the commit (also singular) on the right side.  That way you see what changed between parent and child: what the author of that commit changed in that commit.

But there are commits that have *two* parents.  These commits are called *merge commits;* the `git merge` command tends to build them.  (We cannot say that it *always* builds them, because—as is very common with Git commands—`git merge` can actually do one of several different tasks, depending on the situation and some command-line arguments.)  Given this kind of merge commit, `git log` does not just pick *one* parent, and then show you the diff between that one parent's snapshot and the commit's snapshot.  It does not pick the two parents and diff them—that's usually not very sensible and would not tell you anything about the merge result—and it does not even *attempt* to compare all *three* commits at the same time, at least not by default.

Instead, what `git log` does with a two-parent (or more-than-two-parent) *merge* commit is to show you the log message, and then *not bother to show a diff at all.*  This is actually the most practical thing to do in most cases, which is why it's what `git log` does.  But that immediately tells us that we're definitely not getting a full picture!

#### You *can* get diffs from merge commits

Note that with a nice simple linear chain of commits:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

what `git log` does is start with the *last* commit–it has some hash ID, but here I'm just going to call it `H`—and show you its authorship and log message, and then extract two snapshots, one from parent `G` and one from `H` itself, and diff them.  Then it moves on—or backwards—to commit `G`.  Now it shows you `G`'s author and log message, and then extracts the snapshots for `F` (parent of `G`) and `G` and diffs them.  This repeats, with Git moving backwards, commit-by-commit, from child commit to parent.  It's just at *merges* where `git log` doesn't bother diff-ing at all.

The `git show` command is very similar to `git log`: it mostly does what `git log` does, but only for *one* commit.  That is, if you give `git show` the hash ID of commit `G`, it will show you `G`'s author information, and its log message, and a diff from `F` to `G`, but then just stop there—it won't move on to show `F` too.  But if you point `git show` to a *merge* commit, it *will* show a diff, at least sometimes.  What it shows is a *combined diff*, which is described just a bit further on in these manual pages.  It's important to note that combined diff *still* leaves stuff out, on purpose.  In particular, pay close attention to the (separate) section of the documentation that mentions that:

> combined diff lists only files which were modified from all parents.

This, again, is actually *intended* to be helpful.  Sometimes, it *is* helpful.  The documentation is not very clear about it all, though.  In this case it's not clear why `git log` shows nothing and `git show` produces a combined diff.

What's going on here is that `git log`, and `git show`, and various other commands *can* do this sort of special combined-diff thing.  But by default, `git log` doesn't bother.  You can give `git log` a `-c` or `--cc` flag—note that the first one is "one dash, one c" and the second is "two dashes, two c's"—to make `git log` produce combined diffs for merges.  The `git show` command *defaults* to `--cc` behavior.

Last, note that you can, instead, give `git log` and `git show` a `-m` flag.  In this case, the commands will treat merges even more specially: for a merge commit *C* with two parents *P1* and *P2*, the two commands will, in effect, run:

`git diff P1 C`
`git diff P2 C`

after showing you the usual header information (author and log message).

In all cases, unless you use `--graph`, `git log` *does not* give you enough information to reproduce the actual commit graph—which is crucial for understanding `git merge`.  But that's for another day...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/j6t hos noticed this post, and [proposes](https://public-inbox.org/git/fac55175-dc1e-addf-194b-97aaf6a33e3b@kdbg.org/):

> A poster on Stackoverflow was confused that the documentation of `git-log`
>   promised to generate "patches" or "patch files" with `-p`, but there were
>   none to be found.
>   Rewrite the corresponding paragraph to talk about "patch text" to avoid the confusion.
>
> Shorten the language to say "X does Y" in place of "X does not Z, but Y".

That would read as:

> Running `git diff` without the `--raw` option, or `git log`, `git diff-index`, `git-diff-tree`, `git diff-files` with the `-p` option **produces patch text instead of the usual output**.
>   You can customize the creation of patch text via the `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` and the `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` environment variables.

---

This translates, with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), into this documentation fix:

See [commit 0eb7c37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0eb7c37a8a54557a836a225b07354b8b16c81e79) (15 Sep 2019), and [commit 6fae6bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fae6bd51851ecfd8a86ee26f788b93559d53c7b) (16 Sep 2019) by [Johannes Sixt (`j6t`)](https://github.com/j6t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 980351d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/980351d1ac4e9eedb65d5ad17f09ff351dba9cbe), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### diff, log doc: say "patch text" instead of "patches"

diff, log doc: say "patch text" instead of "patches"

> A poster on Stackoverflow was confused that the documentation of `git-log` promised to generate "`patches`" or "`patch files`" with `-p`, but there were none to be found. Rewrite the corresponding paragraph to talk about "**`patch text`**" to avoid the confusion.
>
> Shorten the language to say "`X does Y`" in place of "`X does not Z, but Y`".
>
> Cross-reference the referred-to commands like the rest of the file does.
>
> Enumerate `git-show` because it includes the description as well.
>
> Mention porcelain commands before plumbing commands because I guess that the paragraph is read more frequently in their context.

---

The [`git generate-patch` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6fae6bd51851ecfd8a86ee26f788b93559d53c7b/Documentation/diff-generate-patch.txt#L1-L13) now reads:

> `git log` (...) with the `-p` option produces patch text.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -p` generate differences of each commit with its previous commit. The differences are displayed with the patch file format.

But it's not generate a real file by default, it output the content to `stdout` by default. To make it simple, it output the content in your terminal.

You can write the output into a real file by **redirection** like this,

```sh
git log -p > ./test.txt
```